# Rails form runs POST when I need PATCH

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a rails form that I want to use to edit an answer by running the update action (PATCH), but I keep getting this error:

```
No route matches [POST] "/answers/724"
```

This is the form:

```
<%= form_for :answers, url: { action: :update } do |f| %>
<%= f.label(@answer.question.question_text) %>
<%= f.text_area(@answer.answer_text) %>


<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-success" %>
</div>

<% end %>
```

Controller:

```
def edit
    @answer = Answer.find_by(id: params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @answer = Answer.find_by(id: params[:id])
    if @answer.update(answer_text: params[:answer][:answer_text])
      redirect_to '/answers/edit'
      flash[:success] = "Answer Updated"
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
```

How can I get this form to perform a PATCH request and not POST?

Answer (score 0):

you need to explicitly pass the method to `form_for`

```
form_for :answers, url: { action: :update }, html: { method: :patch } do |f|
```